# Is it possible to access entry revisions on the front end?

Tags: channel-entries, safecracker, entries, saving

I am looking to create an entry revision site where I can allow users to access/view these on the front-end.

Is it possible to access these on the front end as it is in the control panel?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might see this article http://www.sidd3.com/get-entry-revisions-in-expressionengine/. I hope, it would help you.

Comment: I have developed plugin for it. One can download the plugin from http://www.sidd3.com/entry-revisions-plugin/

Comment: Amazing. Super work! This will be really helpful.